# INDEX, Match combination

Tags: arrays, indexing, row, max, match

I have come across this formula which works in my application but I do not understand how it works
`:=INDEX(MAX(($B:$B<>"")*(ROW(B:B))),0)`

I have broken it down and found that:

`=MAX($B:$B<>"") returns 1` regardless of what is the highest value in column B

```
=ROW(B:B) returns 1
```

if I `input =MAX(($B:$B<>"")*(ROW(B:B)))` as an array formula it returns the row number of the highest non blank cell.

However the INDEX formula does not seen to require an array formula input?

Can anyone please explain?